# ACE graceful exit() function

Tags: exit, ace

Is there a unified ACE function to shut down all existing reactors, threads, pipes etc in current process and allow a safe exit? For example if I have a critical error and want to shut-down my process gracefuly (and make sure it won't get stuck).

Calling `exit()` isn't very thread-safe, especially if there's a reactor listening on another thread.

Answer (score 0):

```
ACE_OS::exit()
```

It won't cleanly exit a reactor loop, or close individual handles, but the OS process run-down is very good at closing things. If you're exiting in response to a critical error, it's not important to hit every element individually.

If you have something like a database to close properly, that's different - you'd have to add "atexit"-type handlers for that.

Comment: My main concern is the process turning into zombie (actually happened couple of times) while stuck in the reactor's events loop. I'll check it out with ACE_OS::exit() and see if it works. Thanks!